# SymPy could not compute the eigenvalues of this matrix

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math, eigenvalue

I want to compute the second eigenvalue of a Laplacian matrix to check if the corresponding graph is connected or not, but when I try to use SymPy's `eigenvals`, a lot of times it happens that it throws an error

```
MatrixError: Could not compute eigenvalues for 
Matrix([[1.00000000000000, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.00000000000000, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        [0.0, 1.00000000000000, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.00000000000000, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.00000000000000, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.00000000000000, 0.0], 
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.00000000000000, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.00000000000000, 0.0], 
        [-1.00000000000000, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.00000000000000, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        [0.0, -1.00000000000000, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.00000000000000, 0.0, 0.0, -1.00000000000000, -1.00000000000000], 
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.00000000000000, 0.0, -1.00000000000000], 
        [0.0, 0.0, -1.00000000000000, -1.00000000000000, 0.0, -1.00000000000000, 0.0, 0.0, 3.00000000000000, 0.0], 
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.00000000000000, 0.0, -1.00000000000000, 0.0, 2.00000000000000]])
```

Looking around I found out that since SymPy does symbolic computation, floating points can be a problem for it. So I tried:

1. To reduce the precision of the floating point `Float(tmp[i][j], 3)`, but it didn't help.
2. I have tried to convert floats to Rational `list(map(nsimplify, tmp[i]))`, but it didn't help.
3. I have tried to convert floats to int `list(map(int, tmp[i]))`, but it didn't help neither.

I really can't understand why it doesn't work out, even if I convert every element to `int`.

Comment: Are you sure that matrix has real eigenvalues?

Comment: If you are fine with a floating point evaluation of eigenvalues, you should prefer either numpy or scipy routines for that purpose. For example, `scipy.linalg.eig` (or, even better, `scipy.linalg.eigh` as the matrix is hermitian) has no problem identifies the eigenvalues

Comment: @internet_user I am sure the matrix has real eigenvalues.

@Stelios I have already seen `scipy.linalg.eigh`, but I wasn't sure about the precision of the eigenvalue, since I need to exactly know if the second smallest eigenvalue is greater or equal than zero. Do you think the numerical computation performed by `scipy.linalg.eigh` will always allow me to retrieve this correct information?

Comment: You can conclude that the graph is not connected from the fact that the 7th row/column of the Laplacian matrix has only zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Laplacian is an integer matrix, let us use integers:

```
L = Matrix([[ 1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0],
            [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0, -1, 0,  0,  0,  0],
            [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0, -1,  0],
            [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0, 0,  0, -1,  0],
            [-1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0],
            [ 0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  3, 0,  0, -1, -1],
            [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0],
            [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  1,  0, -1],
            [ 0,  0, -1, -1,  0, -1, 0,  0,  3,  0],
            [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, 0, -1,  0,  2]])
```

Computing the **eigenvalues**:

```
>>> L.eigenvals()
{0: 3, 1: 1, 2: 1}
```

This is *very strange*, as the matrix is 10-by-10, not 5-by-5.

I tried to compute the Jordan normal form, but could not do it, as function `jordan_form` produced the error message `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Computing the **characteristic polynomial**:

```
>>> s = Symbol('s')
>>> p = (s * eye(10) - L).det()
>>> p
s**10 - 14*s**9 + 77*s**8 - 214*s**7 + 321*s**6 - 256*s**5 + 99*s**4 - 14*s**3
```

Note that the monomial of lowest degree is cubic. This allows us to conclude that the multiplicity of eigenvalue 0 is 3 and, thus, the graph is **not connected**.

Let us try to find the **roots** of the characteristic polynomial:

```
>>> solve(p,s)
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, CRootOf(s**5 - 11*s**4 + 42*s**3 - 66*s**2 + 39*s - 7, 0), CRootOf(s**5 - 11*s**4 + 42*s**3 - 66*s**2 + 39*s - 7, 1), CRootOf(s**5 - 11*s**4 + 42*s**3 - 66*s**2 + 39*s - 7, 2), CRootOf(s**5 - 11*s**4 + 42*s**3 - 66*s**2 + 39*s - 7, 3), CRootOf(s**5 - 11*s**4 + 42*s**3 - 66*s**2 + 39*s - 7, 4)]
```

Note that only 5 roots were actually found (`eigenvals` produced only 5 eigenvalues, too). The 5 missing roots are the roots of the quintic `s**5 - 11*s**4 + 42*s**3 - 66*s**2 + 39*s - 7`.

It has been known since the 19th century that not all polynomials of degree 5 (or higher) have roots that can be expressed using arithmetic operations and radicals. Hence, we may be asking SymPy to do the **impossible**. Better use NumPy to compute approximate values of the 10 eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

You can get numerical approximations of all 10 roots of the characteristic polynomial using `nroots` after bumping up the `maxsteps` parameter for it:

```
>>> p = s**10 - 14*s**9 + 77*s**8 - 214*s**7 + 321*s**6 - 256*s**5 + 99*s**4 - 14*s**3
>>> [i.n(2) for i in nroots(eq,maxsteps=100)]
[0, 0, 0, 0.32, 0.68, 1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 3.2, 4.6]
```

The `CRootOf` instances from `solve(p, s)` are actually solutions, too, that can be numerically evaluated:

```
>>> CRootOf(s**5 - 11*s**4 + 42*s**3 - 66*s**2 + 39*s - 7, 0).n(2)
0.32
```